# error while calling soap ws with basic authentification and ssl

Tags: java, ssl, soap, cxf, basic-authentication

I am facing problem when calling two remote methods from different wsdl which are protected by basic authentication and ssl

the first call is OK but the second call of the second method which is located on an other wsdl don't work

when i call the second method first it works , 
i am using cxf to generate the client it seem that is a bug related to cxf 
i have the same trace error like here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/176959?tstart=0

Comment: give some more details, like your client code and exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi my problem was solved by setting credential using an other methods 
i was using the Authentication class from java.net 
this method is OK when you are using one endpoint with one credential

but if you have multiple endpoint with multiple credential it don't work when you try to call tow method because java net provide a static method that set login and password one time and you are not able to change them for an other call in them same project

the code that success for my case is like that :

```
Hashtable<String, String>  hashmajcompte = new Hashtable<String, String>();

       String      ENDPOINT_URL_CloudAgence=Util.getSysProp("address.cloud.agence");
       String BASIC_USER_CloudAgence= Util.getSysProp("login.cloud.agence");
       String BASIC_PWD_CloudAgence=Util.getSysProp("password.cloud.agence");

       JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryCloudAgence = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();


        factoryCloudAgence.setServiceClass(LdapCloudAgenceWSImpl.class);
        factoryCloudAgence.setAddress(ENDPOINT_URL_CloudAgence);
        LdapCloudAgenceWSImpl serviceCloudAgence = (LdapCloudAgenceWSImpl) factoryCloudAgence.create();

        BindingProvider bpCloudAgence = (BindingProvider)serviceCloudAgence;
        bpCloudAgence.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, BASIC_USER_CloudAgence);
        bpCloudAgence.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, BASIC_PWD_CloudAgence);


    try { 
        serviceCloudAgence.creerMajCompte(login, password, ncli); 
        hashmajcompte.put("Succes", "Succes"); 
    }  

    catch (NamingException_Exception e) 
    {  
        hashmajcompte.put("NamingException_Exception", e.getMessage()); 
    }
```